# parsing strings with escape sequences to another software with python

Tags: python, string

I am using python for another application, I need to parse some text to another file

```
totalVolume=10
mainBlockID=75
volumeIDSet=[]
volumeIDSet= list(xrange(1,totalVolume-2))

a="geom.cmd('subtract volume " 
a1= "subtract volume "
b= ' '.join(map(str, volumeIDSet))
c= " from volume %d keep')" %(mainBlockID)

d=a+b+c    
print d
d1=a1+b+c
```

I get printed on screen, which is correct

```
geom.cmd("subtract volume 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 from volume 75 keep')
```

But, I get following error

```
ERROR: Unrecognized symbol: '%'
ERROR: syntax error (<stdin>, line 26384)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

when I do

```
geom.cmd(" %s ") %(d1)
```

The question is why can I not parse d1 as string? regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom.cmd(" %s ")` returns a `NoneType` and not a string.

You probably want

```
geom.cmd(" %s " %(d1) )
```

Note that this is equivalent to

```
geom.cmd(d1)
```

Comment: it is still not parsing the complete string. Is there a special command for that? For single word strings, it worked for me.

Comment: What do you mean with "parsing the string"? Do you mean the `geom.cmd()` call? Or something else?